# TypeScript extension of type from npm package not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, types, websocket

I use the `ws` package to work with WebSockets in Node.js. I want to add a custom `isAlive` attribute to the `WebSocket` class. My current approach is the following:

```js
// globals.d.ts
import "ws"

declare module "ws" {
  interface WebSocket {
    isAlive?: boolean
  }
}
```

However it does not work. The compiler shows the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'isAlive' does not exist on type 'import("/Users/user/Code/project/node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts")'.
```

The code is the following:

```js
import WebSocket from "ws"

function heartbeat(ws: WebSocket) {
  console.log(ws.isAlive)
  ws.isAlive = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is correct. Assuming you have the extended interface in it's own `.d.ts` file such as the `globals.d.ts` file you referenced, simply add it to the types in your `tsconfig.json` and your IDE should pick it up.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "./globals.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

EDIT: Additionally, you may need to import WebSocket directly instead of using the default export

```
import { WebSocket } from 'ws';

//vs

import WebSocket from 'ws';
```

Comment: I don't event need to add it to the `tsconfig.json `. Not using the default export solves the problem. Could you explain why?

Comment: Nice, that's good to hear. That makes sense now that you mention it.

The default export can technically be named anything, so it doesn't necessarily mean you're importing the WebSocket class, you're just naming the module WebSocket, which overlaps the name of the interface you're extending. You could call `import asdf from 'ws'` and it would be the same thing.